# Multilingual text fields with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am currently evaluating SQLAlchemy for a project. Here is my schema:

- a LANGUAGE table, with a row for each language supported
- a TRANSLATION table with (ID, LANGUAGE_ID, STR)
- various tables will, instead of storing text, store TRANSLATION_IDs, for example, BOOK(ID, TITLE_TRANSLATION_ID, ABSTRACT_TRANSLATION_ID)

Now, assuming each request has the current language ID available (for example, through a thread variable...), I would need SQLAlchemy to automatically join the TRANSLATION table, and thus have text fields in the current language. Something like:

```
class Book(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = TranslatableText()
    abstract = TranslatableText()
```

When retrieving, the ORM would automatically join to the TRANSLATION table with the current language ID, and my_book.title would give me the title in the current language.

I also need this to work across relations: if a class contains foreign keys to other classes that also contain translatable text fields, I would ideally like those to be retrieved too.

Lastly, I would also need to be able to get to the TRANSLATION_ID for each field, for example through my_book.title_translation_id.

I am not expecting a complete solution, but I'd like to know if something like this is feasible, and where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the concept of http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html#mixin-and-custom-base-classes

Create one top level class and write some funciton like read, write and create. Always call that function to create or read data from the database.

If you dont want to implement the mixin classes then also you can use event http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.translate_row